# Really specific formatting issue with bulleted lists

Tags: bug, formatting, css

Here's what happens in a bulleted list that also has subbullets when a bullet's text continues *after* a subbullet:

> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
>   - Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
>   Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. [*Yuck!* This is the problem!]
>
>   Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

For readability and standardization, a [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), empty line, or whatever you want to call it should be between the text of the subbullet and the continuation of the text of the main bullet (that is, between the paragraph beginning *Ut enim* and the paragraph beginning *Duis aute*.)

Obviously, this is no emergency, arises rarely enough that it's possible I'm the only one who's noticed, and may never concern *you*, but I've *restructured answers* so as to avoid having that continuing bulleted text flush with subbulleted text, so I figured I should bring it up.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up a minor frustration of mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This has been "fixed" with the CommonMark update

Below is how we can properly format such things:

> - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
>
>   - Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. [*Yuck!* This is the problem!]
>
> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Apparently just updating this list to work in CommonMark fixes the whitespace issue: we add `>` in-between quotes so they aren't separated, and we add some spaces for indentation so that the second bullet point is properly indented.

The Bot hasn't updated the original post, so the HTML from the old markdown generator is still “baked in”.

### The original

*Before* the [CommonMark change](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9996/we-have-commonmark) (see the [announcement on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)), here's what happens in a bulleted list that also has sub-bullets when a bullet's text continues *after* a sub-bullet (preserved here in an image, as editing the original post will give a different result):

[image: Example of bulleted list indentation error pre-update]

Notably, there is no white space or gap between "commodo consequat" and "Duis aute".

This is how the post would have looked, had the bot updated it to CommonMark (found using the edit preview on the original post):

[image: Example of bulleted list output post-update]

The Bot *hasn't* made this make this update. It would have changed the visual appearance and I suppose it was a complicated fix.

Answer (score 3):

This issue doesn't occur on the mobile version of the site:

> [image]

So I suggest the SE devs grab whatever they're doing there and do the same on the desktop site. :)

Comment: This issue remains unresolved. (I happened to encounter it again today and found myself restructuring an answer so as to avoid nested lists because this looks so confusing and terrible on nonmobile platforms.)

Comment: Unbelievable… or, actually, totally believable? This issue remains uncorrected even after the quotation style change.

Comment: Believable; given what we now know, the whole thing where devs could track bugs & feature requests across all sites was more of a platonic ideal than something they actually had capacity for.